# How to trigger $_GET request within admin plugin page?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, forms, html

I have this form in my plugin function:

```
<form method="get" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p class="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="do_it_hidden" value="run">
    <input name="do_it" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="DO IT!"> 
  </p>
</form>
```

And this php condition earlier in my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['do_it_hidden'])) {
   // some code to execute here
} else {
   // just show the form
   <form method="get" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p class="submit">
       <input type="hidden" name="do_it_hidden" value="run">
       <input name="do_it" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="DO IT!"> 
     </p>
   </form>
}
```

But after clicking on the button I am redirected to `wp-admin/options-general.php?do_it_hidden=run&do_it=DO+IT` which is not what I want to happen.

After the click I just want to reload the page and check if the get condition is true or not.

How to do that?

**EDIT:**

The problem is that after I click on the button I am redirected to completely different page. My plugin is located here: `options-general.php?page=DD_Awesome_Plugin/DD_awesome_plugin.php` but clicking on the button throws me here: `options-general.php?do_it_hidden=run&do_it=DO+IT`

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!** I find that GET is not working at all! You need to use POST and in the form action you need to type this:

`action="<?php admin_url('options-general.php?page=DD_Awesome_Plugin/DD_awesome_plugin.php'); ?>"`

Damn! It's sometimes so hard to do simple task in WP ;)

Comment: You can use a GET request however by using <form method="get" action="<?php echo admin_url('DD_Awesome_Plugin/DD_awesome_plugin.php'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">, Sounds like your ok with posting though but just wanted to give you some FYI lol, I tested this on my box and it works as intended so it's not just a hunch.

Comment: Because you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` you should be using `POST` anyway. But yes, you _do_ need to provide the _correct and complete_ URI, which you were not doing. That is not WordPress' fault. It is the way that your browser and HTML/HTTP work.

Comment: Yes thank you for that correction, sorry copy and paste got away from me >.<, with a get request you would remove the enctype="" attribute.

Comment: Nop, it's not hard to do simple thing in WP, just test my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && 'do_it_hidden' == $_GET['action'] ) {
   // some code to execute here
} else {
   // just show the form
   <form method="get" action="options-general.php">
     <p class="submit">
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_it_hidden">
       <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['page'] ); ?>">
       <input name="do_it" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="DO IT!"> 
     </p>
   </form>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a redirect in your form handler:

```
if (isset($_GET['do_it_hidden'])) {
    // some code to execute here

    wp_redirect( admin_url( "options-general.php" ), 303 );
    exit;
}
```

The user will be redirected to a clean URL then and barely notice the short URL change. Or use a POST request to avoid a changed URL completely.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted something different. My bad, I have formulated it badly. Please, check my updated code in my question to see what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: @Derfder Try my suggestion. It does what you are asking for.

Comment: So, when I click on the submit button, instead of reloading current plugin page I am redirected somewhere else. So, I need after the click run through my code and check the GET condition and in my case it will be true and the code will be executed, because I have clicked on submit and do_it_hidden is sent. In standard php I would do it like action="the_same_file_as_i_am_in" or maybe even action="". What to put in action="???" so it works in WP plugin admin page?

Comment: The action should be `admin_url( "options.php" )` or `admin_url( "admin-post.php" )`. Then register your form handler for that action, do the work, and redirect.

Comment: "Try my suggestion. It does what you are asking for." The problem is that after I click on the button I am redirected to completely different page. My plugin is located here: `options-general.php?page=DD_Awesome_Plugin/DD_awesome_plugin.php` but clicking on the button throws me here: `options-general.php?do_it_hidden=run&do_it=DO+IT`

Comment: Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="do_it.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In the action part of your form you should include the php file that is responsible for processing that hidden form variable, when the form is submitted it will pass that information to the file you specify.  Left blank it will post back to the current page you are on which is not what you want.

For instance the general options form gets directed to the options.php in the admin like so

```
<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It uses that file to process the post information then redirects the user to the display page like so.

```
wp_redirect( admin_url( 'options-general.php?updated=true' ) );
```

Comment: hmm, I have updated my post with additional info. My file where is located the code is called `DD_awesome_plugin.php`

Comment: In php it's so simple to trigger get forms. Is there some tutorial for WP? I don't get it at all. I just want to execute different parts of my spaghetti code depending on which form submit is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['do_it']) && $_GET['action'] =='do_it_hidden') {
   // some code to execute here
} else {
   // just show the form
   <form method="get" action="general.php?page=<?php echo $_REQUEST['page']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p class="submit">
       <input type="hidden" action="do_it_hidden" value="run">
       <input name="do_it" type="submit" class="button-primary" value="DO IT!"> 
     </p>
   </form>
}
```